# JavaScript/JQuery String comparison not working or at least not the way I think it should?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, string-comparison

I have 2 - 2D arrays, "item" and "data2". data2 is a very large array which contains ~22k items that each have a second item(id[0] and name[1]) where as item is a variable length with 9 items each. I am trying to filter through the two arrays to match data[1] to item[0] which both contain the name of the item.

I have tried jQuery.inArray() which i have never used before so im not sure if it will work for sub arrays:

```
for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
        console.log(jQuery.inArray( item[i][0].text, data2 ));
}
```

and then every way I could find or think of doing a normal string compare:

```
for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
        for(var k = 0; k < data2.length; k++){
            if(String(item[i][0].val) == String(data2[k][1].val){
                item[i][6] = data2[k][1];
            }else{

            }
        }
    }
```

I am at a lot of why it wont compare the data. I have also used .text instead I am some what new to JS JQuery so not sure which one I should be using

Array:

item:

```
[0][0]"Armor Thermal Hardener II"
   [1]""
   [2]"Armor Hardener"
   [3]""
   [4]"Low"
   [5]"5 m3"
[1][0]"Armor Kinetic Hardener II"
   [1]""
   [2]"Armor Hardener"
   [3]""
   [4]"Low"
   [5]"5 m3"
[2][0]"Armor EM Hardener II"
   [1]""
   [2]"Armor Hardener"
   [3]""
   [4]"Low"
   [5]"5 m3"
```

data:

```
[0][0]"599"
   [1]"Armor Thermal Hardener II"
[1][0]"600"
   [1]"Armor Kinetic Hardener II"
[2][0]"601"
   [1]"Armor EM Hardener II"
```

Comment: Could you please give us an example of your arrays you want to compare? An example with an array of 5-10 items is enough, just to better understand the scructure

Comment: The documentation from jQuery (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) does mention anything regarding 2D arrays.  However since you are looking specific sub elements in each of the arrays (based on your second example) you are already doing it the best way.

Comment: General note - jQuery is mostly  intended for DOM-related manipulations. If you have to deal with raw data analysis in JS,  check utility libraries like Lodash

Comment: Is that sample data correct? Your code does `item[i][0].val` which suggests your array holds objects, but your sample data only shows strings.

Comment: I was under the impression that you had to use .val/.value to get the value from an array from what I seen on google but that is the correct structure of the array

Comment: So did you try without `.val` or `.text`?

Comment: Yes here are still not matches

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood, you would be better using .filter; besides, I´m not sure about String constructor is ideal, as it will return a String object, which I´m not sure if will perform the comparation as expected; besides, if data2 is so large, I would put its iterator on top; try something like this instead:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++ ){
    var it = item.filter(function(el){ return el[0] == data2[i][1]; });
    if (it.length){ //exists
        it[6] = data2[i][1];
    }
}
```

However, I don´t know what do you pretend using data2[k][1].val on a String; also, doesn´t make much sense to me to check if data2[k][1] is the same that item[i][0] and then assign the same value;  maybe you could explain what does .value means, and I could expand my answer

Comment: `I´m not sure about String constructor is ideal, as it will return a String object` well, it's not really using the constructor `String(variable)` without the `new` keyword will perform type conversion to a primitive string, as opposed to creating a new String wrapper around the primitive.

Comment: Like I mentioned I have tried a lot of different ways to compare the two items that is just what was the last one. Also I tested your code and it come back as anything match. Unless this is possible and I'm not trying to do something that isn't impossible I could just use php

Comment: As I said in my answer, it would really help if you could explaing what is data2[k][1].val and item[i][0].val, as those two don´t make sense to me.

Comment: data2[k][1].val is the the name of the item that has the ID in [0] (in a comment above I was told I did not need .val was not aware of this) and item[i][0] is the name of the item the user entered